# How to count the number of distinct patients from a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I have a table in sql called as New_table with columns such as subj , pred and obj. The column pred contain the string value "patient" and the respective patient ID is available in the obj column.

| subj | pred | obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | Patient | 11452 |
| Subject1 | institute | BWE |
| Subject1 | Patient | 11462 |

I would like to find the count of distinct patient IDs in the whole table. I tried the method

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT pred) as number
FROM New_table
```

But I could not find a method to access a certain value in a column as such the number of distinct patients in the column "pred".

Comment: Add `WHERE pred = 'Patient'`

Comment: Do you also not want the `DISTINCT` values of `obj` not `pred`?

Comment: Mysql <> SQL server - please correct your tags

Comment: ` SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT obj) as number
FROM New_table
WHERE pred = 'Patient' ` works but how do I check the same from top 20 rows of New_table

Answer (score 2):

Your query would return always 2 as Patient and Institute.

Instead use `DISTINCT obj` as i am guessing that every patient has their individuell number(s)  and you should also exclude every row that is not patient

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT obj) as number
FROM New_table
WHERE pred = 'Patient'
```

To get the top 20 you need also an order , so that you get and determinic result or use RANDOM for the order

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT TOP 20 FROM New_table ORDER BY pred)
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT obj) as number
FROM CTE
WHERE pred = 'Patient'
```

Comment: Thank you. I loaded the first 20 rows of my table and counted the number of distinct patients which were 4 manually. Then ran the code you provided on the first 20 rows , but I got number "68" returned instead of 4. I do not know why.

Comment: 68 on 20 rows is impossible, as you can only have max 20 as count, can you provide a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=495ba81b8a8fca407887d2f54fe860b8 which shows  the behaviour, as my sql server shows correct data

Comment: @jan All people can do is guess when you do not clearly explain your goal supported with reasonable sample data. How **exactly** do you define distinct patient based on the columns you have in your table? It seems your definition does not match the best guess of your readers - so provide more information. Add a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017) with more than 3 rows (20 even!) to help others help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I did not create the table in the data base. I am analysing the table so I do not know the details behind how they created this specific table. Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jan without the original data even sanitized, will help without there is no chance as i said 68 is with 20 rows impossible

Comment: `
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT obj) as number
FROM New_table
WHERE pred = 'Patient'
`
This is my code. Maybe I am taking the data from the whole table instead of top 20. How do I check the count of distinct patients for just top 20 rows of the table?

Comment: _I did not create the table_ It does not matter WHO created the table. You are trying to query the table and you MUST know how the table is structured, the primary and unique keys, and how the data is populated. Comments are not intended for extended discussion. Start with this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2086b831c5eef9e2889955d9bb241f0b) and add the top 20 rows to it and provide the expected output that you manually calculate. Post that new link when done as an update to your question.

Comment: yes you take the whole table into account when you run the code like wrote. you didn't seem to have limited anything

Comment: Thank you. So how could I limit the code to just the top 20 rows of the table and not the whole table?

Comment: I added a solution for that to my answer

Comment: I am sorry, but is it the previous answer? Because when I try that code it gives the number of distinct patient IDs from the whole data which I believe is 68. That is why it was not 4 as I manually counted from the first 20 rows. I would like to know if the number of distinct patient ID is 4 for the top 20 rows instead of the whole table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i made a second answer where first the 20 rows are selected, you must see what rows you want so you have to change the CTE to give you the result set that you want, only saying 20 isn't helpfull, as the selecting process needs to be deterministic or random